# How to choose a file using selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Im automating some flow and now I have a button "choose" that is opening the finder window where I need to select the file I want:

[image]

How can I automate it after clicking on "choose" so I can select a specific file to upload, lets say it's path is

> /Users/username/Desktop/5.png

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the below code

```
WebElement El = driver.findElement(By.id("'fileUploadField'"));
El.sendKeys("c:\\temp\\test.txt");
```

make sure it is in same window if it switch to the window then you need to redirect to that window and then select that file.

Comment: what is the "fileUploadField"? I only have a "choose" button that opens what you see in the image added to the question...its the finder where i need to look for the fily I want to upload @Srikrishna Nadagouda